# pnpm error upon fresh install in embroider app

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js, pnpm, ember-table

I switched to pnpm in most of the apps that I maintain and it's an amazing tool. What I don't understand is how to troubleshoot dependency issues. I would really appreciate some help.

The problem comes from one ember-specific addon, and I opened a [new issue](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table) in their repo, but I'd like to be able to figure out what to do in case issues like that happen with dependencies in general.

---

The error is `Cannot find module ...`, if you add the missing module there's another "missing" one and another one and another one ...

```bash
❯ ember s
Building into /private/var/folders/k0/b1p9d5g94px8gdr10458gv0m0000gn/T/embroider/96cc9c
Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: ember-table]) in ember-table/ember-table/-private/collapse-tree.js

Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'
Require stack:
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/broccoli-babel-transpiler@7.8.1/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/lib/worker.jsError: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'
Require stack:
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/broccoli-babel-transpiler@7.8.1/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/lib/worker.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:157:9)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:195:19)
    at sync (/app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:224:12)
    at sync (/app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/gensync@1.0.0-beta.2/node_modules/gensync/index.js:182:19)
    at /app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/gensync@1.0.0-beta.2/node_modules/gensync/index.js:210:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePlugin (/app-root/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.13/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:83:17)
    at resolvePlugin.next (<anonymous>)


Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/k0/b1p9d5g94px8gdr10458gv0m0000gn/T/error.dump.8c92aeb46d1be7e57b69153a731964ac.log
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. `ember init -sn -sb -sg --no-welcome --embroider`
2. `pnpm install`
3. Confirm no build error `ember s`
4. `ember install ember-table`
5. See the build error `ember s`

#### Environment

```bash
❯ ember --version && pnpm --version && node --version
ember-cli: 4.6.0
node: 14.19.1
os: darwin x64
7.9.4
v14.19.1
```

Comment: does this happen with just pnpm, or other package managers, too?

Comment: does the problem go away if you add `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` to your dependencies? it may be worth opening an issue on ember-table's repo to remove that package, as all browsers support rest spread now.

Comment: The problem goes away when I switch to yarn. When I add `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` to the deps I get error message related to another babel dependency. I gave up after adding ~15 deps. I think the full list is coming from ember-cli-page-object-deps

Comment: The list is too long https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/483601670685720591/1011932991586582628/ember-cli-page-object-missing-peer-deps.txt
And I don't remember exactly how I got this list unfortunately

Comment: it sounds like your dependencies are doing something nasty if switching to yarn (objectively terrible with deps / peers) fixes things.

can you report this issue to ember-table? it wouldn't be the first time they're doing bad stuff with deps

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that’s exactly what   I did, there’s a link to the open issue in description. I just don’t like feeling helpless here  I just hoped there’s a way to tell pnpm to treat ember-table in a *special* way and hoist all of the ember-table deps

Comment: there is actually! tho, not all sub-deps, but you can manually specify certain ones: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#public-hoist-pattern

Comment: Yeah, I tried it out already.


```
// .npmrc
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*ember-table*
```

Comment: did you try adding `@babel/*` as well?

Comment: Woohoo! Adding `@babel/*` to the public host pattern works perfectly!
`
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
public-hoist-pattern[]=@babel/*
`
eslint and prettier are the default values